# qt4 signal is not emitted

Tags: qt, qt-signals

I have a QT4 application which wraps libssh2 in order to communicate with the embedded devices on the network. The following snippet is making me crazy for a while.

```
SSHClient ssh_client(host, 22);

try {
    ssh_client.connect_to_host(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    ssh_client.receive_file(file_name, file_path);
} catch(const SSHException &excp) {
    qDebug() << "test";
    emit console(excp.what());
    return;
}
```

I put breakpoints to `qDebug() << "test";` and `emit console(excp.what());` in debugger, however, they never get hit even though an SSHException is thrown. If i put a breakpoint to the `return;` statement, it stops with no problem.

The output is also strange. `qDebug() << "test"` does what it is supposed to do, but, `emit console(excp.what());` is not emitting a signal. And when the control reaches to the `return;` statement, it returns, again with no problem.

Comment: Did you build your code with some optimization level?

Comment: Which data type is excp.what() ? You might need to register it with the Qt MetaType system. Have a look at [QMetaType class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#details) for details. Also, why do you say the signal is not emitted? (I'll state the obviuos) Have you connnected it with some slot?

Comment: @sergico: No, you do not have to register. Perhaps you can start reading about qmetatype first from the link you pasted so that to understand what it is good for? :) Also, the OP said the signal is not emitted because it does not stop there.

Comment: Will need more code ? Atlease your connection statement ! most probably you are connecting signal slot in wrong way.